# Create GIN index in a schema with the pg_trgm extension

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-12, postgresql-extensions

I'm migrating entities from the `public` schema into a new one, let's call it `myschema`. Originally, the `pg_trgm` extension was installed and the index was created in a schema migration with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX mytable_gin_index_on_mycolumn
    ON mytable USING gin (mycolumn gin_trgm_ops);
```

To do the same within `myschema` I modified the migration to look like this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm WITH SCHEMA myschema;
CREATE INDEX mytable_gin_index_on_mycolumn
    ON mytable USING gin (mycolumn gin_trgm_ops);
```

However, index creation fails with the following error:

> operator class "gin_trgm_ops" does not exist for access method "gin"

I tried namespacing the operator class:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm WITH SCHEMA myschema;
CREATE INDEX mytable_gin_index_on_mycolumn
    ON mytable USING gin (mycolumn myschema.gin_trgm_ops);
```

but got the same error:

> operator class "myschema.gin_trgm_ops" does not exist for access method "gin"

I also tried to install the extension without specifying the schema, which yields the same error.

What is the right way to use the pg_trgm extension in a schema other than `public`?

Comment: "I tried namespacing the operator class (myschema.gin_trgm_ops) to no avail"  That works for me.  Please show the entire command you tried to execute and the error you got.

Comment: @jjanes I've updated the question with the detail.

Comment: That still works for me.  What version of PostgreSQL are using?  Was this the first error, or was there some earlier error (for example, did the CREATE EXTENSION...WITH SCHEMA actually succeed?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) before running the DDL statements:

```
set search_path = myschema,public;
```